# c++: using constexpr to XOR data doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, constexpr

Here is my code:

```
template<int... I>
class MetaString1
{
public:
    constexpr MetaString1(constexpr char* str)
        : buffer_{ encrypt(str[I])... } { }

const char* decrypt()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof...(I); ++i)
        buffer_[i] = decrypt1(buffer_[i]);
    buffer_[sizeof...(I)] = 0;
    return buffer_;
}

private:
    constexpr char encrypt(constexpr char c) const { return c ^ 0x55; }
    constexpr char decrypt1(constexpr char c) const { return encrypt(c); }

private:
    char buffer_[sizeof...(I)+1];

};


#define OBFUSCATED1(str) (MetaString1<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5>(str).decrypt())



int main()
{

    constexpr char *var = OBFUSCATED1("Post Malone");

    std::cout << var << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

This is the code from the paper that I'm reading [Here](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-14/materials/eu-14-Andrivet-C-plus-plus11-Metaprogramming-Applied-To-software-Obfuscation-wp.pdf?fbclid=IwAR3EkvQOiJ_0Q8eL3XY94FSiYry-HybaBhUBVv6fM9PSWkZYhXQ8l_ouTss). The Idea is simple, to `XOR` the argument of `OBFUSCATED1` and then decrypt back to original value.

The problem that I'm having is that `VS 2017` gives me error saying `function call must have a constant value in constant expression`.

If I only leave `OBFUSCATED1("Post Malone");`, I have no errors and program is run, but I've noticed that if I have breakpoints in `constexpr MetaString1` constructor, the breakpoint is hit, which means that `constexpr` is not evaluated during compile time. As I understand it's because I don't `"force"` compiler to evaluate it during compilation by assigning the result to a `constexpr` variable.

So I have two questions:

1. Why do I have error `function call must have a constant value in constant expression`?
2. Why do people use `template` classes when they use `constexpr` functions? As I know `template` classes get evaluated during compilation, so using `template` class with `constexpr` is just a way to push compiler to evaluate those functions during compilation?

Comment: You create a temporary `MetaString1<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5>` object and return a `const char*` to its internal buffer. I think that's what's not `constexpr` in this.

Comment: Btw, `constexpr char *var = OBFUSCATED1("Post Malone")` would reintroduce the original string to obfuctated...

Comment: what is other alternatives to achieve same goal?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: to encrypt string in compilation time.

Comment: `MetaString1<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5>(str)` does it.

Comment: but then I need to decrypt anytime, and store it in variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You try to assign a non constexpr type to a constexpr type variable,
   what's not possible

```
constexpr char *var = OBFUSCATED1("Post Malone")
//              ^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^
// type of var is constexpr, return type of OBFUSCATED1 is const char*
```

2. The `constexpr` keyword was introduced in C++11, so before you had this keyword you had to write complicated TMP stuff to make the compiler do stuff at compile time. Since TMP is turing complete you theoretically don't need something more than TMP, but since TMP is slow to compile and ugly to ready, you are able to use `constexpr` to express things you want evaluate at compile time in a more readable way. Although there is no correlation between TMP and `constexpr`, what means, you are free to use `constexpr` without template classes.

To achieve what you want, you could save both versions of the string:

```
template <class T>
constexpr T encrypt(T l, T r)
{
    return l ^ r;
}
template <std::size_t S, class U>
struct in;
template <std::size_t S, std::size_t... I>
struct in<S, std::index_sequence<I...>>
{
    constexpr in(const char str[S])
        : str_{str[I]...}
        , enc_{encrypt(str[I], char{0x12})...}
    {}
    constexpr const char* dec() const
    {
        return str_;
    }
    constexpr const char* enc() const
    {
        return enc_;
    }

protected:
    char str_[S];
    char enc_[S];
};
template <std::size_t S>
class MetaString1
    : public in<S, std::make_index_sequence<S - 1>>
{
public:
    using base1_t = in<S, std::make_index_sequence<S - 1>>;
    using base1_t::base1_t;
    constexpr MetaString1(const char str[S])
        : base1_t{str}
    {}
};
```

And use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr char str[] = "asdffasegeasf";
    constexpr MetaString1<sizeof(str)> enc{str};
    std::cout << enc.dec() << std::endl;
    std::cout << enc.enc() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: what's the point of saving encrypting if I save unencrypted string in executable?

Comment: With my code, you don't save them in the executable, the compiler will throw away the data after compiling is done, that's the purpose of `constexpr`. But don't ask me for further sense of this, I just answered your question.

Comment: @Ojs I think I missunerstood you. You have to make your function `decrypt` return a new string object (e.g. std::string).